# Sublime Text: use Node from nvm for build

Tags: node.js, shell, sublimetext3, sublimetext, nvm

I'm using [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3), and Node is installed locally through [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

How can I create a [JS build](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html) so that it automatically uses the `current` or `default` Node version alias from nvm?

Currently my Sublime build is like this:

```
{
  "cmd": ["~/.nvm/versions/node/v5.9.1/bin/node", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.js"
}
```

The problem with this setup is that the path is hard coded and needs to be changed any time Node is updated. Instead, I'd like the Sublime build to be something like:

```
{
  "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.js"
}
```

or

```
{
  "cmd": ["$NVM_BIN", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.js"
}
```

or

```
{
  "cmd": ["nvm run default", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.js"
}
```

Unfortunately none of them work, since `nvm.sh` has not been sourced.

Any idea how the Sublime build could be set up to satisfy the requiremennts above?

Thanks!

Comment: If you source `nvm.sh` in `.profile` (not in `.bashrc`) it should be available to ST. Otherwise you could try something like `"shell_cmd": "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm run default $file"` (Use an array for `cmd` and a string for `shell_cmd`). Aside: Escape "\\$NVM_BIN" if you want sublime to pass it forward.

Comment: Hi @r-stein, thanks for the advice! I've tried running the `"shell_cmd"` that you suggest, but I get this error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm run default'`. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: The python subprocess.Popen function does not seem to know the `source` command even with shell enabled. You could try: `"shell_cmd": "bash -c \"source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm run default $file\""` to run it in a bash. If you have whitespaces in the path then use `$file_name` instead of `$file`.

Comment: @r-stein you are doing God's work. Thank you! That did the trick!